# MingW and MStask

Tags: mingw, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to use mstask, the windows task scheduler from an application using MingW.

However if I just include the windows mstask.h, I get compiler clashes, with re-defined bits.

Has anyone done this before?  Is there an MingW way of getting to the Windows task scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

MinGW-w64 seems to have the headers. Take at look at the tdm64-gcc compiler suite [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download). Nice installer, current versions, works for me generating 32- und 64bit binaries on windows 7 64.

You may have to link against some of MinGW-w64's libraries, for example the ole32. This linker command worked for me:

```
g++ "-LC:\\progs\\MinGW64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\lib" -static -o TaskScheduler.exe "src\\TaskScheduler.o" -lole32
```